# H2 database integer data conversion error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

This is my model class:

```
package com.arizonainc.dev.eLibrarySystem.models;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Book {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

private String title;
private String genre;
private String author;
@Column(nullable = false)
private int availableQuantity;

protected Book() {
    
}

public Book(String title, String genre, String author, int availableQuantity) {
    super();
    this.title = title;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.author = author;
    this.availableQuantity = availableQuantity;
}
```

This is my data.sql file in src/main/resources:

```
insert into BOOK values (10001, '12 Rules For Life', 'Non-fiction', 'Jordan Peterson', 5);
insert into BOOK values (10002, 'Maps of Meaning', 'Non-fiction', 'Jordan Peterson', 4);
insert into BOOK values (10003, 'Crime and punishment', 'Fiction', 'Fyodor Dostoevsky', 3);
insert into BOOK values (10004, 'Peace and War', 'Fiction', 'Leo Tolstoy', 3);
```

This is the error message in the console:

```
Data conversion error converting "'Non-fiction' (BOOK: ""AVAILABLE_QUANTITY"" INTEGER NOT NULL)"; SQL statement: insert into BOOK values (10001, '12 Rules For Life', 'Non-fiction', 'Jordan Peterson', '5') [22018-200]
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, specify explicitly the sequence of fields in the INSERT statement:

```
insert into BOOK(id, title, genre, author, availableQuantity) values (10001, '12 Rules For Life', 'Non-fiction', 'Jordan Peterson', 5);
insert into BOOK(id, title, genre, author, availableQuantity) values (10002, 'Maps of Meaning', 'Non-fiction', 'Jordan Peterson', 4);
insert into BOOK(id, title, genre, author, availableQuantity) values (10003, 'Crime and punishment', 'Fiction', 'Fyodor Dostoevsky', 3);
insert into BOOK(id, title, genre, author, availableQuantity) values (10004, 'Peace and War', 'Fiction', 'Leo Tolstoy', 3);
```

This should solve the issue.

If you don't specify the sequence of fields explicitly in the **INSERT** statement, then the order might not be, as you expect it.

In your example, **H2 INSERT** statement expects "**availableQuantity**" field on the **3rd** position, for some reason.